Determining $P$(jumps|apple)

$$P(\text{frog}) = 0.1, P(\text{apple}) = 0.9, P(\text{frog}|\text{jumps}) = 0.9, P(\text{apple}|\text{jumps}) = 0.1.$$

I have been given the above information, and want to determine the value of $P(\text{jumps}|\text{apple}).$
The answer key says that $$P(\text{jumps}|\text{apple})=0.01,$$ but how was this obtained?  I tried using Bayes' Theorem, but am missing the value of $P(\text{jumps}).$

EDIT, after the first answer below was posted, to add additional information:
This problem is a Bayesian inference problem, which I got from a book called Active Inference: The Free Energy Principle in Mind, Brain, and Behavior. Here's a screenshot of how the problem is solved, but I don't get the solution.  

[1] Can you tell us from where you have got this problem ? [2] What does "jumps" supposed to mean in the contect [3]  What have you tried so far, can you edit it in. ?

This is confusing. P(frogs|jumps) + P(apple|jumps) = 0.9 + 0.1 = 1. Since there are only frogs and apples, doesn't that mean everything jumps. P(jumps) = 1

This can be solved if frog and apple are mutually exclusive. Is that the case?

@Hudjefa Your conclusion doesn't actually follow from that sum.

@ryang. really? $0.9 + 0.1 = 1$, no?

@Hudjefa In the example below, you can work out that P(jumps)$=0.108\ne1.$

@Wei it is mutually exclusive

@Hudjefa the object is either a frog or an apple

@ryang, correct (?). Multiple solutions consistent with the info provided by the OP.

@RohitShenoy, si and $0.9 + 0.1 = 1$. Doesn't that mean $P(jumps) = 1$

@Hudjefa The point is that the example below already proves that P(frogs|jumps) + P(apple|jumps) = 1 doesn't imply that P(jumps)=1.

@ryang, yes I completely forgot that I upvoted your answer (providing a range of possible values for the answer). That was really neat. What's got me confused is of the things that jump (say 10), 9 are frogs and 1 is an apple. So given something is either an apple or a frog, $\text{P(jumps)}= 0.9 + 0.1 = 1$. We're not talking about anything but apples & frogs.



$$P(\text{frog}) = 0.1, P(\text{apple}) = 0.9, P(\text{frog}|\text{jumps}) = 0.9, P(\text{apple}|\text{jumps}) = 0.1.$$

The answer key says that $P(\text{jumps}|\text{apple})=0.01,$ but how was this obtained?

The given information implies that $P(\text{jumps}|\text{apple})$ can possibly equal any number in $\left[0,\dfrac1{81}\right],$ including $0.01.$
For example, observe that $$P(\text{jumps}|\text{apple})=0.012\ne0.01\\P(\text{jumps}|\text{frog})=0.972$$ is consistent with the given information.

$\text{P(Jumps|Apple)} = \frac{\text{P(Jumps)} \times \text{P(Apple|Jumps)}}{\text{P(Apple)}}$
$\frac{\text{P(Jumps|Apple)}}{\text{P(Jumps)}} = \frac{\text{P(Apple|Jumps)}}{\text{P(Apples)}}$
$\frac{\text{P(Jumps|Apple)}}{\text{P(Jumps)}} = \frac{0.1}{0.9} = \frac{0.01}{0.09} = \dots$
